# Weekly local notification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have a small question how could I do a weekly local notification. My app is about a time table when the user has a class on 8 o'clock then there is a switch when user tern the switch on that mean he has a notification on 7:45 to remained him every week on the same time . I hope u understood me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `repeatInterval` with `NSWeekCalendarUnit`

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit; 
localNotification.fireDate = yourDateandTime;
localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Alert Fired aton every week at 7:45Am"];
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

It will repeat every week on same time.You can refer and download example from this [tutorial](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/09/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html)

Comment: I'm sorry but your code where chould I paste it ?? And how could I link it with switch. i'm sorry again I'm in beginner level in programing and it's my first application.

Comment: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/09/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html refer this link provided in answer

Comment: Ok that was helpful but what is the day ? I mean what should I wrote in ( yourDateAndTime ) if I wanna repeat every monday .